# jquery ui dialog .load and blank dialog in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-ui-dialog

i've got several pictures surroundes by a-tags and when you click on them, the link of the a-tag should be opened in a dialog, what works fine, except in IE8 (IE9 works fine)...

```
$('a.modal').each(function() {
    var $link = $(this);

    $link.click(function() {

       var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
        .load($link.attr('href') + ' #content')
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal:true,
            width: 762
        });

        $dialog.dialog('open');
        return false;
    });

});
```

there are no visible errors in the console. somebody might has an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally it had not really something to do with a wrong javascript-code but with the uselessness of ie and its discapability to resolve urls, so it worked with the startpage, and with urls in raw-form but not with transformed permalinks, changing the whole thing to ajax helped:

```
    $('a.modal').click(function() {

        $.ajax({url: $(this).attr('href')})
        .done(function( html ) {
            var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
            .html(html)
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: true,
                modal:true,
                width: 762
            })
        });
        return false;
    });
```